# Mysql date sorting is incorrect

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
co.id,
IFNULL( oe.follow_status, 'unFollow' ) AS followStatus,
co.due_time 
FROM
car_order co
LEFT JOIN order_expire oe ON oe.order_id = co.id 
WHERE
co.type = '贷款' 
AND co.STATUS = '已放款' 
AND co.approve_status != '结清成功' 
AND date_FORMAT( co.due_time, '%Y-%m-%d' ) <= '2022-10-29' 
ORDER BY
field( oe.follow_status, 'unFollow', 'follow' ),
co.due_time DESC,
co.id DESC
```

[image]

The date sort is wrong. How should I write it?

Comment: Just order by followStatus, due_time DESC, id DESC.

Comment: `oe.follow_status` is probably `NULL` for those records. You should order by the IFNULL-alias `followStatus` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `due_time` be a timestamp column, you should be able to directly compare it against a date literal:

```sql
SELECT co.id,
       IFNULL(oe.follow_status, 'unFollow') AS followStatus,
       co.due_time 
FROM car_order co
LEFT JOIN order_expire oe ON oe.order_id = co.id 
WHERE co.type = '贷款' AND 
      co.STATUS = '已放款' AND
      co.approve_status != '结清成功' AND
      co.due_time <= '2022-10-29' 
ORDER BY FIELD(oe.follow_status, 'unFollow', 'follow'),
         co.due_time DESC,
         co.id DESC;
```

The `DATE_FORMAT()` function is used for converting dates/timestamps into strings, but you don't need this here as date/timestamp columns can be compared directly.

Comment: I tried it. It's still wrong

Comment: That depends on what your meaning of the word "it" is.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
co.id,
IFNULL( oe.follow_status, 'unFollow' ) AS followStatus,
co.due_time 
FROM
car_order co
LEFT JOIN order_expire oe ON oe.order_id = co.id 
WHERE
co.type = '贷款' 
AND co.STATUS = '已放款' 
AND co.approve_status != '结清成功' 
AND co.due_time <= '2022-10-29' 
ORDER BY
field( followStatus, 'unFollow', 'follow' ),
co.due_time DESC,
co.id DESC
```

You should order by the IFNULL-alias followStatus instead.